# Is there any equivalent to pragma pack(1) in Fortran for derived types?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am encapsulating a C function that returns an array of structs.

I define the equivalent derived type in Fortran as:

```
    type, bind(c)   :: myrecord
            integer(c_int)          :: a
            integer(c_int)          :: b
            real(c_double)          :: c
            real(c_double)          :: d
            real(c_double)          :: e
            real(c_double)          :: f
            integer(c_int)          :: g
            integer(c_int)          :: h
            integer(c_int)          :: i
    end type
```

When I check its size I get 448 (56 bytes):

```
type(my_record) :: x_myrecord
print *,storage_size(x_myrecord)

448
```

However, in C, due to pragma pack(1) usage its size is just 52 bytes.

This is a problem as I am receiving an array of structs, and while the first item of the array is properly received, the subsequent ones are not, as the values for the fields are misplaced (incremental offset of +4 bytes for each subsequent record).

Is there any way to force Fortran to use packed structs like in C compilers (gcc/clang)?

Comment: Five by four byte integers (twenty bytes) plus four by eight byte reals... does not give 48 bytes.  Show the C declaration of the type.

Comment: My mistake I will correct that, it is 52 bytes instead of 48. I see that the first field of the second element of the array in Fortran contains the second field of the second element of the array in C.

Comment: The issue here is that while the components of the struct themselves are naturally aligned, an array of these would misalign every other element. I see that Intel Fortran will let you bracket the type declaration with !DIR$ OPTIONS /ALIGN=(RECORDS=PACKED)...!DIR$ END OPTIONS - you'll get a compile warning about the potential misalignment but you'll get the size you want. gfortran may have a similar extension. There is nothing in the Fortran language that will help you here.